# IAsyncActionFilter, trying to log request body, but it is empty

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

Im trying to set up IAsyncActionFilter to log request body for some API requests.
But when I try to read body stream I get empty string every time.

Here is my code:
StringContent is always an empty string, even tho there is an json body on post requests.

```
    public async Task OnActionExecutionAsync(ActionExecutingContext context, ActionExecutionDelegate next)
    {
        ActionExecutedContext rContext = null;
        string stringContent = string.Empty;

        try
        {
            context.HttpContext.Request.EnableBuffering();
            context.HttpContext.Request.Body.Position = 0;

            using (var reader = new StreamReader(context.HttpContext.Request.Body))
            {
                stringContent = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();

                context.HttpContext.Request.Body.Position = 0;
            }

            rContext = await next();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
```

I dont want to use middleware, becouse I need to log only some of the controllers.

Comment: this seems to work OK on my side, don't even need to use `EnableBuffering`. So you need to find the cause somewhere else. First ensure that the json body can actually be received by your server.

Comment: Json is Ok. Controller and Actions work just fine. Only problem is I cant read the body in action filter.

Comment: so it's strange because I've tested it on my side, it just works perfectly. No `EnableBuffering` used anywhere. But the environment may be different from yours because it's `asp.net core 2.2`.

Comment: I'm running .Net 5

Comment: Ok... So I Found this: https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/5260, ModelBinding runs before action filters so if you have form data or a [FromBody] parameter, then it wont work. So I have to find a new way to implement logging.

Comment: ah yes, that makes sense. The model binding may remove the request body, if no model binding occurs, it will remain. I think the answer below is acceptable, buffering request may need extra memory, that's the main trade-off. Your requirement is to read the request body ***anyway*** so you can try to enable buffering only for a selective set of requests as early as possible. The info for selecting which requests to handle is unfortunately not available at the early points (before mvc middleware). I'm not sure but the new *endpoint* feature may provide some info at the early phase.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The request body has already been read by the MVC model binder by the time your IAsyncActionFilter executes https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/5260.

As a quick workaround, you could add

```
app.Use(next => context =>
        {
            context.Request.EnableBuffering();
            return next(context);
        });
```

in your startup.cs Configure() **BEFORE** your `UseEndpoints` call

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.Use(next => context =>
            {
                context.Request.EnableBuffering();
                return next(context);
            });

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
        }
```

Of course, this would enable request body buffering for all of your requests, which may not be desirable. If that's the case, you would have to add some conditional logic to the EnableBuffering delegate.

Comment: This actualy worked. But why is the request being read before the ActionFilter? I dont have any other filters or midleware executirng before this actionFilter.

Comment: So Ive alredy found the answer. ModelBinding runs before action filters (github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/5260). Could you add that to your answer?I'l mark it as accepted.